# How can I undo a mysql statement that I just executed?

Tags: mysql, rollback

How can I undo the most recently executed mysql query?

Comment: This sounds like an "oops I just deleted the database" kind of moment.

Comment: Need help too. I just emptied all my tables caused by error in code

Comment: ... could just as easily be a bad WHERE clause!

Comment: that link maybe helps https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/02/20/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-an-innodb-tablespace/

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you define table type as InnoDB, you can use transactions. You will need set `AUTOCOMMIT=0`, and after you can issue `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` at the end of query or session to submit or cancel a transaction.

```
ROLLBACK -- will undo the changes that you have made
```

Answer (score 42):

You can only do so during a transaction.

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO xxx ...;
DELETE FROM ...;
```

Then you can either:

```
COMMIT; -- will confirm your changes
```

Or

```
ROLLBACK -- will undo your previous changes
```

Answer (score 25):

Basically: If you're doing a transaction just do a rollback. Otherwise, you can't "undo" a MySQL query.

Answer (score 7):

For some instrutions, like ALTER TABLE, this is not possible with MySQL, even with transactions ([1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html) and [2](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28727)).

Answer (score 5):

You can stop a query which is being processed by this

Find the Id of the query  process by  => show processlist;

Then                                  => kill  id;

Answer (score 1):

in case you do not only need to undo your last query (although your question actually only points on that, I know) and therefore if a transaction might not help you out, you need to implement a workaround for this:

copy the original data before commiting your query and write it back on demand based on the unique id that must be the same in both tables; your rollback-table (with the copies of the unchanged data) and your actual table (containing the data that should be "undone" than). 
for databases having many tables, one single "rollback-table" containing structured dumps/copies of the original data would be better to use then one for each actual table. it would contain the name of the actual table, the unique id of the row, and in a third field the content in any desired format that represents the data structure and values clearly (e.g. XML). based on the first two fields this third one would be parsed and written back to the actual table. a fourth field with a timestamp would help cleaning up this rollback-table.

since there is no real undo in SQL-dialects despite "rollback" in a transaction (please correct me if I'm wrong - maybe there now is one), this is the only way, I guess, and you have to write the code for it on your own.