# How can I recovery mysql data which there is no data backup and no bin-log?

Tags: mysql, data-recovery

I used update sql to update a table,but i forget "where",one column all data to null.
How can I do to let the data recovery to before update operate?
Please help me!!

Comment: I think this is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918831/how-to-undo-mysql-query).

Answer (score 3):

If you define table type as InnoDB, you can use transactions (see the link below). You will need set AUTOCOMMIT=0, and after you can issue COMMIT or ROLLBACK at the end of query or session to submit or cancel a transaction.

```
ROLLBACK -- will undo the changes that you have made
```

Comment: My table type is MyISAM,There have .MYI\.MYD\.frm files in data directory, and now there is a select operate after update...

Comment: If you committed your transaction, it's time to dust off that backup, sorry. But that's what backups are for. I did something like that once myself. No luck for that. There is no way you can undo that.

Comment: Is the Binary Log enabled?

Comment: ...I hope that God save me , or it's all over!

Comment: Even you have Binary Log Enabled that doesn't mean anything. According to [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/01/01/how-to-use-mysql-binlogs-to-undo-a-drop-statement/). You cannot use the binary logs to undo unwanted changes to your data.

Comment: If i have Binary Log I can recovery it to the log datatime.Most of the data can be obtained.