# PHP : How to rollback last query execution in myphpadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have created one table and entered 10 records but one record is having wrong information so i updated that but query went wrong and values are updated in all the records.

So now i want to rollback my previous query execution.

Any help is most welcome!!!

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no rollback. Unless you have a backup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to undo mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918831/how-to-undo-mysql-query)

Comment: The only way to rollback is if you use transactions. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918831/how-to-undo-mysql-query

Comment: Truncate the table and start again.  This is a development environment, right?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately,
You don't have any chance to rollback last query.
Query log doesn't save no where.