# delete or undo the first query if the second query did not work

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

im confused about this. Is there any way like to test if all queries are working and not returning erros? if so execute them or return something.

I am building a signup method, this have 2 parts: loginInfo(username, password) and the usual Employee info (name, email, etc..).

The signup method inserts the Employee info into `employee` table, then it gets the PRIMARY key and insert it alongside with the loginInfo in the `login` table

the `login` table has an `UNIQUE` column, this should return error on duplicated. The problem is that the `employee` info are inserted without a `login` information.

How can i solve this problem?

My code:

```
public function signUp($personInfo, $employeeInfo, $loginCredit){
    try {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT 
            INTO `$this->employeeTable`
                (`name`, `birthDay`, `phnNmb`, `email`, `address`, `idnNmb`, `insNmb`, `bankInfo`)
            VALUES
                (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
        ");

        $stmt->execute([
            $personInfo["name"],
            $employeeInfo["birthDay"],
            $personInfo["phnNmb"],
            $personInfo["email"],
            json_encode($employeeInfo["address"]),
            $employeeInfo["idnNmb"],
            $employeeInfo["insNmb"],
            json_encode($employeeInfo["bankInfo"])
        ]);

        $employeeId = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();

        $insertloginCredit = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `$this->loginTable` (`empId`, `userName`, `userPass`) VALUES ($employeeId, ?, ?);");
        $insertloginCredit->execute($loginCredit["userName"], md5($loginCredit["userPass"]));

        echo "done";

    } catch (\PDOException $err) {
        die($err->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: you are doing it in a wrong architectural way, login and registration should be on the same table

Comment: @Psycho why should login and registration be on the same table? The employee details are likely used elsewhere in the program in areas which don't require the login details - equally login functions such as logging in/out, password resets and suspending accounts have no need to know about the user profile details

Comment: Yes, you can undo your last insert if you define table type as InnoDB. [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918831/how-can-i-undo-a-mysql-statement-that-i-just-executed)

Comment: okay I understand

Comment: @imposterSyndrome thx guys for the information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for here is called a transaction. The PDO docs have some [explanation on them](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php). In summary, you'd want to do the following.

```
try{
  $this->pdo->beginTransaction();
  $stmt1 = $this->pdo->prepare(...);
  $stmt1->execute(...);
  $stmt2 = $this->pdo->prepare(...);
  $stmt2->execute(...);
  $this->pdo->commit();
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
  $this->pdo->rollBack();
}
```

The `rollBack` function will restore the database to the state it was in when `beginTransaction` was called.

Comment: Thank you. yeah this is what i was looking for. nice name btw. :)

Comment: just some notes: if you have auto incremented primary keys then there might be some keys missing if any exception occurs when you use **rollback** operation. I am mentioning this because I faced some issues here.